# C text inverting always prints unwanted '%' in the end

Tags: c, linux

I have this small code that is only inverting the text in a file character by character and its working perfectly fine, the problem is that it always adds a '%' at the end.

```
FILE *fd;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])  {

if ((fd = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != NULL){
    int ft = 0;
    int i = 0;

    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

    ft = ftell(fd);
    while(i < ft)
    {
        i++;
        fseek(fd, -i, SEEK_END);
        printf("%c", fgetc(fd));
    }
    printf(" ");
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

        fclose(fd);
    }

    else {
        perror ("File does not exist !!!\n\a");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The input text is : `Taco cat`

And the output is : `tac ocaT %`

So i can't find a way to get rid of this pesky % sign.
Im in linuxmint.

Comment: `perror(argv[1])` is better than `perror("File does not exist!!!")`.  Consider the confusion caused by: `"File does not exist!!!: permission denied"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For using `FILE` include `<stdio.h>` header.
checking for file opening can be go outside if statement it makes more readable.

After finish work add a `\n` to output.

**the code so far**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  FILE *fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (fd == NULL) {
    perror("File does not exist !!!\n\a");
  }

  int ft = 0;
  int i = 0;

  fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

  ft = ftell(fd);
  while (i < ft) {
    i++;
    fseek(fd, -i, SEEK_END);
    printf("%c", fgetc(fd));
  }
  printf(" ");
  fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

  fclose(fd);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

For more accuracy check result of `fseek()` which is return zero on success.

Here grab from manpage, `man fseek`.

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>    The rewind() function returns no value.  Upon successful completion, fgetpos(), fseek(), fsetpos() re‐
>    turn 0, and ftell() returns the current offset.  Otherwise, -1 is returned and errno is set  to  indi‐
>    cate the error.
> ```

Answer (score 8):

The `%` is your shell prompt. It's not from the program. The reason it looks weird is that you forgot to print a `\n` at the end of the string.